# How can I remove duplicates while multiprocesscing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am very new to multiprocessing and I am only using it to find an image on the screen, the problem is the code produces duplicates which slow it down I have tried using a "not in" statement to only place proc into processes if it is not already in it, but this did not work. Any help or optimization would be welcome I have no idea what I am doing as this is just a personal project to learn multiprocessing.

```
from multiprocessing.context import Process
import pyautogui as auto
screenWidth, screenHeight = auto.size()
currentMouseX, currentMouseY = auto.position()
def bot(aim):
    while True:
        for aim in auto.locateAllOnScreen(r"dot.png", confidence=0.9795):
            auto.click(aim)
            print(aim)
def bot2(aim):
    while True:
        for aim in auto.locateAllOnScreen(r"dot.png", confidence=0.9795):
            auto.click(aim)
            print(aim)
def bot3(aim):
    while True:
        for aim in auto.locateAllOnScreen(r"dot.png", confidence=0.9795):
            auto.click(aim)
            print(aim)            
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    processes = []
    for t in auto.locateAllOnScreen(r"dot.png", confidence=0.9795):
        proc = Process(target=bot, args=(t,))    
        processes.append(proc)
        proc.start()
    for z in auto.locateAllOnScreen(r"dot.png", confidence=0.9795):
        proc = Process(target=bot2, args=(z,))    
        processes.append(proc)
        proc.start()
    for x in auto.locateAllOnScreen(r"dot.png", confidence=0.9795):    
        proc = Process(target=bot3, args=(x,))    
        processes.append(proc)
        proc.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless my eyes deceive me, you have three functions `bot`, `bot2` and `bot3` that appear to be identical. You have to ask yourself why you need three identical functions that differ only in a name. I certainly don't have an answer.

Presumanly `auto.locateAllOnScreen` returns the locations of all occurrences of "dot.png" on your screen and you would like to print out information on each occurrence in parallel. Your main process is iterating all of these occurrences 3 times and for each occurrence staring a new process. Then each process is totally ignoring the occurrence argument, *aim*, that is being passed to it and instead iterating all the occurrences itself. So if there were 5 occurrences on the screen you would be creating 3 * 5 = 15 processes and each process would be printing 5 lines of output (one for each occurrence) for a total of 15 * 5 = 75 lines of output when in reality you should only be getting 5 lines of output if you were doing this correctly (I am ignoring that there is a `while True:` loop where all the output is then repeated). You are also potentially creating more processes than the number of CPU cores you have on your computer and so they would not truly be running in parallel *on the assumption that the `bot` function(s) are CPU-intensive*, which may not be the case.

I am not sure whether this problem is a candidate for multiprocessing since there is a fair amount of overhead just to create processes and to pass arguments and results to and from one process to another. So you might not gain any improvement in performance. But if the idea is to see how you would solve this using multiprocessing, then I would suggest that if you do not know in advance how many elements the call to `auto.locateAllOnScreen` might return and recognizing that there is no point in creating more processes than the number of processors you actually have, then it is probably best to use a *multiprocessing pool* of fixed size.

What you want to do is have your worker function `bot` (and you only need *one* of these) be passed a single occurrence that it will process. You then create a pool of processes equal to the smaller value of the size of the number of CPUs you have and the number of tasks you actually have to submit. You then submit to the pool a number of tasks where each task specifies the worker function to perform that task and the argument(s) it requires.

In the code below I have removed from function `bot` the `while True:` loop that never terminates. You can put it back in if you want.

```python
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import pyautogui as auto

def bot(aim):
    # do the work for the single occurrence of aim
    auto.click(aim)
    print(aim)            
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    aims = list(auto.locateAllOnScreen(r"dot.png", confidence=0.9795))
    # choose appropriate pool size:
    pool = Pool(min(len(aims), cpu_count()))
    # bot will be called for each element returned by call to auto.locateAllOnScreen
    pool.map(bot, aims)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful and you are correct on multiple fronts, the "bots" can be CPU intensive but my CPU has plenty of cores and threads available for both multiprocessing or multithreading. I am currently trying to change the bots so that they look at 3 divisions of the screen to share the load. Your answer is definitely helpful and I appreciate the contribution.